# Formula based on Conditional Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm quite new to using formulas so please bear with me. I have 10 columns that have conditional formatting which will shade cells green or red to indicate pass or fail. What I need is for the 11th column to fail a case if any one of the other columns fails; the problem I'm encountering is that I can't use a generic "if yes, pass; if no, fail" as some columns pass with yes, while others fail.

Example: Column D "Contains Signature Form" - Yes will pass, no will fail; Column F "Document has been Revised" - Yes will fail, no will pass.

[image: Current build]

Is there a formula I can use based solely on the conditional formatting (e.g. if a cell in any column is Red, the overall criteria will fail) or am I doomed to use several formulas to accomplish this?

Comment: The conditional formatting is based on some formula or test for each cell.  Build a formula in the 11th column that reevaluates those same conditions and determines if any fail.  There isn't a formula function that can determine the color of a cell, but I believe you could do that with VBA, if you want to go that route.

Comment: Better you attach sample data will help us to fix the issue ! You said 11th column should fail if any other columns has fail,, what I've realized that if any of the 10 columns has fail then 11th should fail ,, write?

Comment: @RajeshS, correct; I've added a screenshot of the current formatting of the file. Referencing the image, Cell M2 failed because E2 and F2 both fail the criteria check; what I need is formula that will fail the M column so long as a single cell fails the criteria check. It doesn't matter how many checks pass, if a single one fails, the M column needs to reflect the fail. Hope this gives a little more detail!

Comment: @ArgentKing, if this is the criteria, "if a single one fails, the M column needs to reflect the fail. " then in this case all rows in M col will be Fail(no), coz No which represents Fail resides everywhere !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but if you have the "Passing" criteria housed in a cell, you can reference that against the row using an IF formula. Then it doesn't matter how each column is formatted, as you're comparing data to data.

Below (using your image as a refernece), I created a string in B8 of what the passing criteria is for all the cells.

Then, the formula in column M checks the string in the row against the correct value in B8. If it matches, you're good. If anything in that row is different, a No is returned.
Formula in M2. Drag to copy down as many rows as you need, keeping the "check cell" absolute with $'s

```
=IF((C2&D2&E2&F2&G2&H2&I2&J2&K2&L2)=$B$8,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Now, all you need to do is format your "Eligible?" cells as an "=Yes" or "=No".

Not an ideal solution for a long string of columns. But, if you're only working with 10, this might do the trick. Good luck!

Note: Put the reference cell (in this case, $B$8) somewhere where it will not get overwritten. I'd recommend a hidden column to the right of your table or a protected cell.

Comment: This worked perfectly! The help is greatly appreciated!!